# Where is 'command' finding my command?

Tags: zsh

I have a shell function that looks like this:

```bash
rebar3 () {
    set -o localoptions -o localtraps
    trap '/bin/stty sane' INT
    command rebar3 "$@"
}
```

How do I find out where `command rebar3` is finding the `rebar3` binary?

I've tried the following, none of which work:

```
% which rebar3
rebar3 () {
    set -o localoptions -o localtraps
    trap '/bin/stty sane' INT
    command rebar3 "$@"
}
```

...not helpful.

```
% command -v rebar3
rebar3
```

...not helpful.

```
% command -V rebar3
rebar3 is a shell function from /Users/rogerlipscombe/.zshrc
```

...I already knew that.

```
% command -p rebar3
zsh: command not found: rebar3
```

...because the binary is not in the default path.

**How do I get zsh to ignore functions / aliases when using `which` or `command -v`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POSIX way works in zsh:

```
(unalias rebar3 2>/dev/null; unset -f rebar3 2>/dev/null; command -v rebar3)
```

The POSIX way of doing the `PATH` lookup explicitly also works. Here I show a simple way that assumes that `$PATH` has no empty components.

```
(IFS=:; set -f; for p in $PATH; do ls $p/rebar3 2>/dev/null; done)
```

Zsh has a much simpler way of doing a path lookup, thanks to the [`path` array](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-path) and the `N` [glob qualifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers).

```
print -lr $path/rebar3(N)
```

Alternatively, starting from the idea that you want something approximately like `command -v rebar3` or or `type rebar3` or `which rebar3`, look up the documentation of the [`command`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-command-1), [`type`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-type) or [`which rebar3`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-which), all of which show that these are wrappers around the [`whence`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-whence) builtin. This leads you to

```
whence -p rebar3
```

to show external commands only, or one of

```
whence -a rebar3
type -a rebar3
```

to show everything (aliases, functions, builtins external commands). `which -a rebar3` also works but it displays the code of functions which is a distraction here.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14196212/8446

> In ZSH, `which` is equivalent to `whence -c` (showing function's definitions), not `whence -p` (which tells executable path). If you want to change that, make an alias.

```
% whence -p rebar3
/opt/homebrew/bin/rebar3
```

Comment: I was about to suggest `which rebar3` vs `command which rebar3`. In my testing the first returns the function and the second returns the executable